# Apple iOS 64-Bit App Update

Tags: ios, app-store

I have updated my app to 64-bit just fine. Everything is according to Apple's standards. I pushed the new version to the store and it got accepted on the 1st of July 2015.

Now, here is the problem, some customers are reporting that the app is not being updated automatically from the store. In other words, they still have the old app on their devices. And when you go to the store to manually update it, it installs a new version of the app next to the old one and they end up with 2 apps (same app) with the old and new version. Also some other customers are reporting that they are seeing mixed data when they lunch the new app (like data from the old one still shows up on the new one)

FYI, the bundle ID and the app ID are the same, nothing has changed except the app version and build number!

I have been publishing app for few years now and I have not seen such a problem. Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way a user can end up with two copies of the app being installed is if the two apps actually have two different bundle ids. What do you have in iTunes Connect? One app or two?

Comment: @rmaddy its one app, same bundle same id! its very weird.

Comment: If you **truly** believe the Bundle ID & App ID's are the same but the app is being installed again and not upgrading an app already installed then there is a bug in iOS or the App Store and you should report it to Apple. But you had better be sure that there is only one app in iTunes Connect and the Bundle ID & App IDs are correct and the same before reporting this.

Comment: @RoboticCat Thanks a lot! Thats what I'm thinking, it is for sure the same app id and bundle, and its the only one there!